# Python + Flask web app reports "[Errno 9] Bad file descriptor" with pexpect module

Tags: python, linux, flask, pexpect

I am developing a web app using Python + Flask. In the simplest sense, a request from the client to a specific URL will trigger the app to login into a remote machine on the server side, perform a series of shell commands, and parse and send the output (formatted in JSON) to the client as part of the response. These commands are fairly simple. To log in to the remote machine, the only method available to me is *rlogin*, so I used the *[pexpect](https://pexpect.readthedocs.org/en/latest/)* module since I [couldn't find](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-list/2003-November/214498.html) any standard Python modules for *rlogin*.

Now the problem is that while I am able to get the correct output from pexpect/rlogin, sending that output (a string) as a response results in an error:

```
----------------------------------------
Exception happened during processing of request from ('171.71.55.54', 62736)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/isan/python/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 295, in _handle_request_noblock
    self.process_request(request, client_address)
  File "/isan/python/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 321, in process_request
    self.finish_request(request, client_address)
  File "/isan/python/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 334, in finish_request
    self.RequestHandlerClass(request, client_address, self)
  File "/isan/python/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 651, in __init__
    self.finish()
  File "/isan/python/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 710, in finish
    self.wfile.close()
  File "/isan/python/python2.7/socket.py", line 279, in close
    self.flush()
  File "/isan/python/python2.7/socket.py", line 303, in flush
    self._sock.sendall(view[write_offset:write_offset+buffer_size])
error: [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor
----------------------------------------
```

I've stripped the code down to the bare minimum required to reproduce the error. An HTTP request to this app results in the "Bad file descriptor" error. Sorry for the varying indentation, I was using two different editors to modify the code!

```
import os
import subprocess
import pexpect

from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

class rlogin:
        def __init__(self, host, prompt):
                self.child = pexpect.spawn("rlogin " + host)
                self.prompt = prompt
                self.child.expect_exact(self.prompt)

        def command(self, command):
                self.child.sendline(command)
                self.child.expect_exact(self.prompt)
                response = self.child.before
                return response

        def close(self):
                self.child.close()

@app.route('/')
def index():
        rl = rlogin("myserver", "root@myserver:~# ")
        output = rl.command("pwd")
        rl.close()
        # The output of the next line is just as I expect:
        print output
        # This is probably where it fails:
        return output

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', debug=True)
```

Removing the calls to `rlogin()`, `rl.command()` and `rl.close()`, and returning a simple string like "A" resolves the error. I've been stuck on this issue for a while now, and would hugely appreciate any help. Thanks!

Comment: You can't expect Flask to figure out how to render an output of the pexpect response object, or whatever is your child.before pointing to. What's the type of the output variable?

Comment: The type of the `output` variable was `str`. I double checked that to be sure.

Comment: Look at the solution for [This link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34509746/ssh-persistent-connection-using-pxssh-in-flask).

Answer (score 1):

You will have to make sure that the return type is str, unicode, response class or WSGI function. It looks like your output doesn't belong to any of the accepted Flask route return types.

```
@app.route('/')
def index():
        rl = rlogin("myserver", "...")
        output = rl.command("pwd")
        rl.close()
        print type(output)
        # Convert output into something that flask can understand
        value = str(output)
        resp = make_response(value)
        resp.headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/plain'
        return resp
```

You can read more about this at http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/api/#flask.Flask.make_response

Comment: Thanks Boris, I tried this, but unfortunately it doesn't affect the output. In the original code, I was parsing the output of `rl.command()` and converting it into a dictionary (supported by Python's `json` module) and then stringifying it using `json.dumps`. Which was then returned in the response.

Comment: @Jayant You should be able to return a string from the flask endpoint. What happens if you return a dummy string from the endpoint, and not output variable?

Comment: So there are two scenarios: (1). It fails if I keep the calls to `rlogin`, AND return a dummy string from the endpoint. But the output of `rl.command()` is OK. (2). It works if I remove the call to the `rlogin` constructor and the subsequent calls AND return a dummy string from the endpoint. I know that these sort of hint towards an issue with the `rlogin` class instead of the flask stuff, but then why does it fail in the endpoint return? Could it be that the fact that the same application is trying to communicate on two different TCP ports (for rlogin and server) is causing this fault?