# SSH persistent connection using pxssh in flask

Tags: python, ssh, flask, pexpect

I am working on web interface to run command on remote servers using pxssh. Is there anyway I can create persistent ssh connection, below code calls connect_ssh for every request.

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify, render_template, request, g, current_app
from flask import _app_ctx_stack
from pexpect import  pxssh

app = Flask(__name__)


def connect_ssh():
    s = pxssh.pxssh()
    s.login('localhost', 'user', 'passwd')
    return s

def get_ssh():
    top = _app_ctx_stack.top
    if not hasattr(top, 'ssh_conn'):
        top.ssh_conn = connect_ssh()
    return top.ssh_conn



@app.route('/_remote_cmd')
def remote_cmd():
    cmd = request.args.get('cmd', '', type=str)
    ssh = get_ssh()
    ssh.sendline(cmd)
    ssh.prompt()
    res = ssh.before
    return jsonify(result=res)


@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run('0.0.0.0')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try calling:

ssh = connect_ssh()

only once under "app = Flask()" line and rerun it and it will run only once.

Comment: Now I am getting AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'ssh_conn'

Comment: Thanks usre42635, I moved the get_ssh inside below block and its getting called only once                                                                                                               with app.app_context():ssh = get_ssh()